# Know if a variable is a native object in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, native

is there a way to know if a variable passed into a function is a native object? I mean, i have a function that requires only native objects as arguments, for every other type of variable it throws an error. So:

```
func(Array); //works
func(String); //works
func(Date); //works
func(Object); //works
...
func([]); //Throwr error
func({}); //Throws error
```

I want to know if there's a way to distinguish between native objects and everything else.

Comment: Javascript is pretty mushy.  Also, `[]` *is* an Array.

Comment: Yes but Array is a function because it's the constructor of the Array object

Comment: Oh I see - you want to operate on the constructor functions themselves.

Comment: I think that empty hash is the shortcut for new Object(). Can you please give a more "detailed" case - why do you need such functionality? I'm sure there's a better solution rather then detecting what is native.

Comment: @Juriy: Yes. `{}` is the same as `new Object()` just as `[]` is the same as `new Array()`.

Comment: @mck89: Obviously you don't have to answer, but I'd love to know the use case for this...

Comment: I have a class system implemented in javascript. A class can extend only another class or a native object, so i need to check that the object to extend is a class or a native object

Comment: @mck89: I think the term *"built-in constructor"* is more accurate than *"native object"* for this case.

Comment: The _types_ Array and Object are _built-in objects_, but not the instances of these, they are _native_. This is defined per the ES262-3 spec. For more info see http://jibbering.com/faq/#objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to do an `===` (or `!==`) against the list of accepted values (which wouldn't be that long, from your question), being aware that that could be tricked into thinking something wasn't a native that was (just from another window).

But basically:

```
if (obj !== Array &&
    obj !== String &&
    obj !== Date &&
    /* ...and so on, there are only a few of them... */
   ) {
    throw "your error";
}
```

**Edit** Re my comment about things from other windows: Be aware that constructors from one window are not `===` to constructors from another window (including iframes), e.g.:

```
var wnd = window.open('blank.html');
alert("wnd.Array === Array? " + (wnd.Array === Array));
```

alerts **"wnd.Array === Array? false"**, because the `Array` in `wnd` is not the same as the `Array` in your current window, even though both are built-in constructors for arrays.

Comment: I didn't know that you can do that type of comparison, thanks. So i think that this is the only way right? There's no way to do a common check for every constructor?

Comment: @mck89: As far as I know, no, there's no shortcut way. (BTW, I edited my answer to explain the window thing better.)

Comment: this is the most comprehensive answer I have ever received thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, current "best practice" way to get the type of something is

```
var theType = Object.prototype.toString.call(theObject);
```

That'll give you a string that looks like "[object Array]".

Now, keep in mind that `[]` is an Array instance, and `{}` is an Object instance.

Comment: If you try to to this with native objects you'll get always [object Function] beacause they are all functions, so there's no way to distinguish them because every other function has the same result

Comment: OK - I typed that under a misunderstanding of your question. Your question title asks about "native objects", when it seems that what you're really interested in is the set of constructor functions that create native objects.  See Mr. Crowder's answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a "typeof" operator in JavaScript that might help.

```
alert (typeof arg)
```

The other (a little more sophisticated) approach is to use

```
arg.prototype.constructor
```

this will give the reference to a function that was used to construct the object